# How to setup Grafan Log panel to display system log writh talagraf+influxdb

Tags: grafana, influxdb, telegraf

I want to use Grafana v6.6.2 with Telegraf+InfluxDB to display the content of /var/log/kern.log log file from a Log panel.

I can see the log data from InfluxQl, I can also see them from the **Explore** view by selecting "Logs" query, then select syslog->message measurement.

But, within a dashboard, I cannot setup the Log panel.

Here is the query I'm using in the Log panel configuration:

> SELECT mean(*) FROM sysMonitor.autogen.syslog WHERE $timeFilter GROUP
>   BY time($__interval) fill(null)